# Cannot link to lib file after upgrading to VS10

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, linker

So I imported this VS9 solution into VS10 and VS10 would convert the whole thing into its new format for solution and project files. However, now it is giving me linker errors.

One project, a native C++ project, is using a set of header files and a `.lib` file to link to some external library. In the project, this library is specified by being put into a "Library" folder in the project. In VS9, this works fine, in VS10, it fails. The same lib is linked, however, when put into the "Additional Dependencies" setting in the Linker Input panel of the project's options.

I know the technique to drop lib files into the project for more than a decade. Has this stopped working with VS10?

Comment: Wow, I didn't knew about the "drop libs into the project" thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No ,that still works in VS2010 (just tested it to make sure)!

Comment: Thanks. I can't believe I failed to check on that. So there must be some differences between what I did and what your simple test case does. Mhmm. I wish I had time to tinker with this and find out... Anyway, you get the bounty for coming up with the obvious test, even though this doesn't answer why it doesn't work in my case. Thanks!